# Filtering in ExtJS combobox with multiSelect set as true

Tags: extjs, combobox, multi-select

Is there a way to enable filtering in combobox with multiSelect enabled ?
I know multiSelect has been deprecated and Sencha recommends using tagfield, but my requirement is for combobox.
For the first time the filtering works fine, but next time the selected values are not retained.

Comment: I recommend you use tagfield because tagfield is such a combobox with ability to select multiple choices. can you explain your problem with a little code;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, combobox is not retaining the previous selection on selecting the next filtered option.

For this, I looked into the `valueCollection` array of Combobox, which stores the selected records. In `getValue` method, selection is explicitly getting removed. Seems like they haven't thought about multiselect in this case.

We can add a simple check in the override to have it fixed:

```
Ext.define('Overrides.form.Field.Combobox', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    getValue: function() {
        var me = this,
            store = me.getStore(),
            picker = me.picker,
            rawValue = me.getRawValue(),
            value = me.value;
        
        if (!store.isEmptyStore && me.getDisplayValue() !== rawValue) {
            me.displayTplData = undefined;
            // BEGIN OVERRIDE
            if (picker && !me.multiSelect) {
                me.valueCollection.suspendEvents();
                picker.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                me.valueCollection.resumeEvents();
                me.lastSelection = null;
            }
            // END OVERRIDE

            if (store.isLoaded() && (me.multiSelect || me.forceSelection)) {
                value = me.value = undefined;
            } else {
                value = me.value = rawValue;
            }
        }
        
        me.value = value == null ? null : value;
        return me.value;
    }
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3nro

Comment: Thanks Devendra, the fiddle is working as expected, however there is a minor concern, if I try to remove the selected item by clicking backspace or delete in the selected area after comma(for example try to delete 1019 after comma), that item still remains intact and do not remove from the selected items. when we select only one item then it works correctly and remove the selected item on clicking backspace